# Angular 6: Passing object from component to service

Tags: angular

I want to pass my object from component to service class. I know there are some possible ways in angular series, but you can suggest me a good method to achieve this goal, big thanks for good suggestions and codes.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code with us, Enrique?

Answer (score 4):

you should simply define a setter getter for your service:
component:

```
constructor(private myService:MyService){}
ngOnInit(){
    this.myService.setData(this.obj);
    this.myServcie.getData();
}
```

MyService:

```
setData(obj){
    this.obj = obj
}

getData(){
    return this.obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i want to pass my object from a function, the function get that data from an emitter, that local data should be passed to the service,possible?

Comment: @Enrique_Iglesias yes it's possible you can call the setter getter of service in every function you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use either `@Input()` and `@Output` variables. `@Input()` for passing data from parent to child component, and `@Output()` to emit an event from child component to parent component. For `@Output()` you must listen to the emitted event in parent component.

Also, you can use a shared service as mentioned and return `observables` using `subjects`.

```
private subject = new Subject();
public obsForComponent = this.subject.asObservable();

setValue(condition: any){
    this.subject.next(condition) // Sets the new Observable value that can be listened in components 
}
```

In your component on `ngOnit` or in the template just reference the `service.ObsForComponent.subscribe(value=>...)`, and if you want to set/emit new obs, `service.setValue(something)`

Answer (score 0):

Like Fateme said you can use setter and getter but as follows:

Component:

```
yourHandler() {
  this.service.myfunc = {
    property1: "SomeValue",
    property2: "AnotherValue"
  }
}
```

Service:

```
object: {};

set myfunc({...obj}) {
  this.object = {...obj}
}

get myFunc(): {} {
  return this.object
}
```

And just use myFunc in your other components, without parentheses ()

for example:

From any components:

```
myObj: {};

constructor(private service: MyService) {
  this.myObj = this.service.myFunc;
}
```